# Funding in Bond Market

Tags: bond

Can you please explain what are we usually referring to when we talk about the funding rate of a bond? Also, what is the relation of a repo rate with a bond.

The question is open, so any comment or explanation is welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with repo at all? How it can be used to fund the purchase of a bond?

Comment: I guess not. That’s what I would like to understand